# Process text with weird character

Tags: c++, text, special-characters

I have a text corpus which consists of sentences, one per line. The corpus is in German and some parts of it contain some weird character. For example, when viewed with the `less` command from terminal, here are some of the lines:

> w�hlen sie die zahlen aus, indem sie sie anklicken. sie k�nnen f�r
>   jede runde zwei bis zehn zahlen ausw�hlen.
>
> keno xperiment ist eine erweiterte version vom keno lottery spiel.
>
> nachdem sie ihre auswahl getroffen haben, klicken sie auf eine
>   spielen, um die spielrunde zu starten, oder auf f�nf spielen, um mit
>   den ausgew�hlten zahlen f�nf runden hintereinander zu spielen.
>
> unter dem hauptspielbereich finden sie eine reihe von buttons mit den
>   zahlen 2 bis 10, au�erdem die zufallsauswahl und ein k�stchen mit der
>   bezeichnung �vor jeder runde neue zahlen ausw�hlen�.

(The '�' are in fact just the characters with the Umlaut. Surprisingly, on some lines, these character display perfectly)

I want to process to get rid of the lines what contain these corrupted characters. Here's the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int lengthLowerBound = -1;
int requirePunct = 0;

unordered_map <string, string> specials;

// weird characters
#pragma warning( push)
#pragma warning( disable : 4101 )
bool isOK(char ch) {
  if (ch == '�') return false;
  return true;
}
#pragma warning( pop )

bool isOK(string &line) {
  for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
    if (line[i] == '�') return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// has punctuations
bool hasPunctuations(string &line) {
  for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
    if (ispunct(line[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 5) {
    cout << "Usage: ./Filter input1.txt input2.txt output1.txt output2.txt [hasPunctuation | noShorterThan x]" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  string inpFile1 = string(argv[1]);
  string inpFile2 = string(argv[2]);
  string outFile1 = string(argv[3]);
  string outFile2 = string(argv[4]);

  for (int i = 5; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "hasPunctuation") == 0) requirePunct = 1;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "noShorterThan") == 0) lengthLowerBound = atoi(argv[i+1]);
  }

  // filter
  ifstream finp1(inpFile1, ifstream::in);
  if (finp1.fail()) {
    cout << "  Can't open file " << inpFile1 << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  ifstream finp2(inpFile2, ifstream::in);
  if (finp2.fail()) {
    cout << "  Can't open file " << inpFile2 << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  ofstream fout1(outFile1, ofstream::out);
  if (fout1.fail()) {
    cout << "  Can't open file " << outFile1 << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  ofstream fout2(outFile2, ofstream::out);
  if (fout2.fail()) {
    cout << "  Can't open file " << outFile2 << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  string line1, line2;
  int numLines = 0;
  cout << "# Start tokenizing" << endl;
  while (getline(finp1, line1)) {
    getline(finp2, line2);

    if (line1.empty() || line2.empty()) continue;

    if (!isOK(line1) || !isOK(line2)) continue;

    if (lengthLowerBound > 0) {
      if (line1.length() < lengthLowerBound || line2.length() < lengthLowerBound) continue; 
    }

    if (requirePunct) {
      if (!hasPunctuations(line1) || !hasPunctuations(line2)) continue;
    }

    fout1 << line1 << endl;
    fout2 << line2 << endl;

    ++numLines;
    if (numLines % 1000 == 0) cout << "\r  Read " << numLines/1000 << "k lines.";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "# Done" << endl;

  fout2.close();
  fout1.close();
  finp2.close();
  finp1.close();

  return 0;
}
```

If you just copy the code above and run it with appropriate command as guided in the code itself, on the given sentences, you will see that the code doesn't do anything. I suspect this is because the comparison `ch == '�'` is always false. There is actually a warning.

So, my question is how to do what I want to? And it doesn't need to be in C++. Python, Perl, or the `sed` command, anything, is highly appreciated. Thanks.

TL;DR: I want to process a text file to get rid of all the '�' characters as in the quoted text.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is that you're processing the text as if it were ANSI, and those Umlauts might be outside the ANSI range. Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, it's a great primer.

Comment: Embedding unusual characters in your source code might not work. Instead you will need to check for the character in another way (e.g. via its intger code or unicode code).

Comment: first find the codepoint for the character with hex editor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `less` does not understand the encoding of your German file: the '�' characters are probably being displayed in place of the actual characters for that reason. The easiest way to filter out these lines is probably to check for non-ASCII characters by seeing if any bytes have the highest bit set:

```
bool isOk(const string& line) {
    return none_of(begin(line), end(line), [](uint8_t c) {return 0x80 & c;});
}
```

This works for UTF-8 encoded text because any non-ASCII code point is encoded as multiple bytes which each have the highest bit set. It also works for more limited 8-bit codes like ISO-8859-1 because the non-ASCII characters are represented by bytes outside of the ASCII range, which must also have the highest bit set.

Answer (score 1):

Just check each character in the string using the functions/methods found in the [cctype.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/)

```
bool isOk(string str) {
    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = tolower(str[i]);
        if(!isalnum(c) && !ispunct(c) && !isspace(c)) // check if not alphanumeric, a punctuation nor white space
            return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: maybe the 'tolower' is not really needed

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that your corpus is (mostly) encoded in a single byte encoding, such as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) (or the closely related [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and ISO-8859-15), while your terminal is expecting the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode.

'�' is the Unicode "[replacement character](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=FFFD)" (U+FFFD); a Unicode output device will typically display invalid codes with an instance of the replacement character.

Since the replacement character cannot fit in a single byte, C compilers will generate a warning when you try to create a narrow character literal from it. You could create a wide character literal, or a unicode string literal, but that's not going to help you because the replacement character is not actually present in the text.

What you really want to do is either:

- convert your corpus to UTF-8, or
- tell your terminal to expect whatever encoding is being used in the corpus.

Which of these you choose will depend on how you want to use the corpus data.

For the first possibility, take a look at the [`iconv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html) utility (there is also a Posix standard library function with the same name). For the second, you'll need to change your locale and possibly the configuration of your terminal emulator. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/characters-encodings-supported-by-more-cat-and-less) on a sister Stackexchange site for some ideas.